# Having only one copy of dll in installation folder which is reference by subapplications too

Tags: wpf, shared-libraries, setup-project

Environment: WPF, .NET 4.0, VS 2010

I am developing an application which has one main app that will internally invoke sub application and the solution structure (mentioned only the required projects for simplicity) is as below:

```
Solution.sln
    MainApp (WPF application)
    SubApp (wpf application)
    Assets (class library)
```

I have added reference to the Assets project into MainApp and SubApp. I added Setup project and:

1. Added MainApp primary output (this detects Assets.dll as a dependency).
2. Created a folder SubApp (right click Application Folder and add new folder) and added SubApp primary output inside this folder). This too detects Assets.dll as dependency (which is correct!)

When I build the setup project, run the MSI and install the application, I see target application folder (c:\program files\default company) structure as below:

```
MainApp
   - MainApp.exe
   - Assets.dll
   - SubApp (folder)
        - SubApp.exe
        - Assets.dll (I don't want this to appear here simply because there will be SubApp1, SubApp2 and so on in future who all will refer to the same assets dll)
```

How can this be achieved? I am sorry if question has become too long but I believe in explaining things in one shot than to provide information in bits and pieces.

Comment: Assets goes in the GAC.

Comment: Can putting assembly into GAC be avoided? If I don't want to put it in GAC, is there any alternative approach?

Comment: Not trivially.  You'd have to override assembly lookups in the domain within `SubApp` and manually load the assembly from the parent directory.

Comment: Only 15 views and 2 comments in 12 days, unbelievable for SO. Any extra efforts that post author has to take in order make it reach maximum people!?

Comment: Well, if you had 75 rep you could start a [bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties).  Honestly, I gave you the answer in comments.  Either throw it in the gac (this is the best option, btw) or attach a listener to the [AssemblyResolve event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve(v=vs.110).aspx) and load your assemblies manually.